# Running process of remote SSH server in the background using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I am finding hard to run a process on a remote SSH server at background using Paramiko. I used :

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('executefile.py &')
```

and found that no process of `executefile.py` was found running.

Then I tried using other way as including a backward slash:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('executefile.py \&')
```

This method worked. There was an instance running on machine but no surprise, it was not running at background. I could come to know as it is not running at background as when code stuck at second line after this code. It was

```
all_inf = stdout.readlines()
```

Now code was not going beyond above line unless the process of the script was killed.

I am learning Paramiko, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

I've tried all the methods described here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396066/paramiko-running-commands-in-background) without success, and finally realized that you need to use channels instead of using the `SSHClient` directly for calling `exec_command` (**this does not work in background**):

```py
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.connect(ip_address, username='root', pkey=paramiko_key, timeout=5)
client.exec_command('python script.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &')
```

You should create and use a channel, **this works in background**:

```py
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.connect(ip_address, username='root', pkey=paramiko_key, timeout=5)
transport = client.get_transport()
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.exec_command('python script.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &')
```

So `nohup`, `dtach`, `screen`, etc, are actually not necessary.

Comment: Just FYI, you do not even need the `&`.

Comment: For me the first code work too. Actually the `SSHClient.exec_command` internally does the same what the second code. The only difference is that it returns output streams. Maybe that can make the difference in some cases. Closing them might solve the difference.

Comment: unfortunalty, that doesnt work for me:( After closing client, the remote process exits too :(

Comment: It's ok for me to use in enbedded system, but not in linux PC.
using `invoke_shell` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('nohup python executefile.py >/dev/null 2>&1 &')
```

Comment: same on asyncssh

Answer (score 3):

`exec_command` isn't executing the command in an interactive shell, so "running a process in the background" doesn't really make sense.

If you *really* want to do this, you could use the command `nohup` to start your process, and keep it alive when the session exits. Remember that you can't get stdin, stdout, or stderr when you do this, since you are detaching the process from the shell, so redirect them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `transport` class and it was really great. Here's the code I used:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname = "host_ip", username = "un"], password = "up")
channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
pty = channel.get_pty()
shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
shell.send("cd /my/directory/; nohup ./exec_name > /dev/null 2>&1 &\n")
```

But I still don't know how to kill it using python scripts; I have an open question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530126/how-to-kill-a-process-on-a-remote-server-using-python-paramiko).

**EDIT 1:**

I have solved my problem about killing the process somehow; you can check it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using screen

```
screen -d -m ping 8.8.8.8
```

This is would start a screen and ping 8.8.8.8. You can view this screen by using

```
screen -ls
```

and attach using

```
screen -D <<screen_name>>
```

Note that the screen will terminate after the command has finished executing.