# How to kill a process on a remote server using python paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, kill-process

I have python script that connects to a remote server with lenny operating system. It runs a process in background using following line:

```
shell.send("cd /my/directory/; nohup ./exec_name > /dev/null 2>&1 &\n")
```

Then after some other codes, it sends a `kill` command to the server to stop process execution; here's the code:

```
shell.send("kill -9 process_pid \n")
```

It returns no error, but doesn't kill the process and it's still alive in the system. I also tried `killall -9 process_name`, but I got the same result. Any help?

For more information, here's the code for connecting to the server:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname = "host_ip", username = "un"], password = "up")
channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
pty = channel.get_pty()
shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
```

I should mention that the user has root privileges.

**EDIT 1:**

I forgot to say that I tried this:

```
ssh.exec_command("kill -9 process_pid \n")
```

But it returned this error:

```
SSHClient is not active right now.
```

**Edit 2:**

As @JimB mentioned in the comment, the problem about `exec_command` is that the transport has been staled. I made a temporary SSH connection and killed the process by that; it was successful. But I'm still searching for a better way.

Comment: But you are sending the real process id right?  Not the string 'process_pid'?

Comment: I think so, but let me double-check!

Comment: Yes, it's actually the real process ID.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have you considered using fabric instead? It makes using paramiko much easier :)

Comment: "I should mention that the user has root privileges." That is actually bad, I think. It could have appropriate `sudo` privileges, but I would consider it dangerous too. In this context, I think, no special power is needed, as user is allowed to kill processes that he owns. At least on every linux system I worked on. Have you tried issuing an equivalent `ssh` remote command from another system by hand ( something like `ssh name@remote "kill pid"`)? The environment set up for interactive ssh, and non-interactive differ a bit on the receiving end. It might turn out to be not python related.

Comment: @Wolph, I have tried `fabric` before, but it does not sufficient for my program. There are some constraints that interfere my work.

Comment: @luk32, I tried to make an SSH connection from another system and kill the process by the above command and it was successful.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi You are ambiguous. Did you issue a remote command, or used interactive ssh connection? There is (or can be) little a difference between interactive and non-interactive ssh mode.

Comment: @luk32, I'm sorry, maybe I just misunderstood your comment. Actually I am talking about a remote command. But I also tried an interactive SSH connection. The former was unsuccessful and the later was successful. I hope I was clear.

Comment: What is the output of, and exit_status of `exec_command`? Also, 'SSHClient is not active right now.' means that you're using a stale transport. Get a transport from your current connection.

Comment: @JimB, There is no error code; the exact phrase is this: `Exception paramiko.SSHException: SSHException('SSH session not active',)`. But thank you for denoting about stale transport. I made a new temporary SSH connection and it successfully killed the process; but I still for a better way to do this, don't you have anything in mind?

Comment: Don't use shell unless you absolutely have to, exec_command is much easier to reason about. You're still not calling get_pty on the same channel as invoke_shell. If the exec_command is failing, and you have to reconnect, then something else went wrong; check your logs.

Comment: @JimB, thanks for your notes. I will debug the code again.