# Launch ssh process in the background with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

#### What I want

I would like to ssh to a remote machine, start a process in the background, and retrieve the pid.

```
mrocklin@notebook:~$ echo hello &    
[1] 29974
hello
```

#### What I tried

I would like to do this same thing with Paramiko

```
In [1]: import paramiko
In [2]: client = paramiko.SSHClient()
In [3]: client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

In [4]: client.connect('127.0.0.1')
In [5]: stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('echo hello &')

In [6]: stderr.read()
Out[6]: b''
In [7]: stdout.read()
Out[7]: b'hello\n'
```

When I do this with a process like `sleep`, `stdout.read()` blocks, cementing the fact that this isn't happening in the background.

#### What I really want

I want to run processes in the background because I want the ability to kill the process based on the PID later if I choose.  Is there a better way to go about launching and killing several processes on a remote machine?

Comment: `stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sleep 5 & echo $!');print(stdout.readline());print("foo")` would get the pid and show the process is not blocking, it is the python read that is blocking

Comment: Perhaps this other SO issue may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560498/running-process-in-the-background